# shifting a column down in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data in the following way

```
     A  B  C  

     1  2  3
     2  5  6
     7  8  9
```

I want to change the dataframe into

```
    A  B  C  

       2  3
     1  5  6
     2  8  9
     3
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to add a blank row to the dataframe and then use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

```
# input df:

    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   2   5   6
2   7   8   9

df.loc[len(df.index), :] = None
df['A'] = df.A.shift(1)

print (df)

     A    B    C
0   NaN  2.0  3.0
1   1.0  5.0  6.0
2   2.0  8.0  9.0
3   7.0  NaN  NaN
```